# Как вводить данные в базу через запятую и получать как два разных обьекта

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Нужно чтобы при новом вводи в один и тот же `<input type="text" name="forever">` в туже строку в базе введенный текст или цифра через запятую, и вывод данных как два разных обьекта, я хочу получать информацию о сериале(к примеру) через id и сразу несколько, но создавать уйму строк в базе как-то не правильно как по мне к тому же сезонов у сериала может быть больше чем 10 а такое кол-во строк создавать это ку-ку получается

Дополнение -

Так я вроде разобрался как заносить id через запятую) Но вот как выводить теперь проблема

```
$pizza  = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "SELECT `linkid` FROM `palace` WHERE `id` = $Param[id] "));

$pieces = explode(",", $pizza[0]);
```

При выводе переменой $pieces выходит значение array а не числа которые лежат в $pizza[0], при выводе же $pizza[0] выводит все числа через запятую как исправить(((

Comment: Создавать уйму строк в базе как-то правильно. А писать через запятую в базе - как-то неправильно. Такие дела

Comment: Если что то ваши 150-200-500 строк для базы семечки.

Comment: Ну через explode разобрать или json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как раз создавать несколько строк в базе - это правильно, а хранить значения через запятую в базе, не является правильной практикой. Для базы данных не составит никакого труда обработать и пару тысяч строк которые Вам нужны.

Так же можно создать отдельную таблицу в которой хранить только например сезоны сериала, и привязывать каждый сезон к id сериала.